# Nextflow script to check adapter content and run trimmomatic

Tags: bash, nextflow, rna-seq

I am trying to write a nextflow script to check the adapter content and trim the sequences that contain adapter using Trimmomatic. Here's my nextflow script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

inputFile = file(params.infile)

logParams(params, "nextflow_parameters.txt")

// Header log info
log.info ""
log.info "========================================="
log.info "Nextflow Version: $workflow.nextflow.version"
log.info "Command Line:     $workflow.commandLine"
log.info "========================================="
log.info ""

// Send FASTQ files to FASTQC, Trimmomatic, and STAR /////////////////////////////////////////

Channel.from(inputFile)
  .splitCsv(sep: '\t', header: true)
  .into {
    readInput_to_runFastQC
    readInput_to_runTrimmomatic
  }

process runFastQC {
  tag "Checking adapter content for ${sampleID}"
  publishDir "${params.output_dir}/Samples/${sampleID}/FastQC"

  module params.modules.fastqc

  input:
  path params.output_dir
  set indivID, sampleID, libraryID, rgID, platform_unit, platform,
    platform_model, run_date, center, R1, R2 \
    from readInput_to_runFastQC

  output:
  file("${sampleID}_001.R1_fastqc/summary.txt") into runFastQC_to_runTrimmomatic_R1
  file("${sampleID}_001.R2_fastqc/summary.txt") into runFastQC_to_runTrimmomatic_R2

  script:
  fastqcDir = "${params.output_dir}/Samples/${sampleID}/FastQC"
 
  """
  module list 

  mkdir -p ${fastqcDir}
  
  # Run FastQC to check adapter content
  fastqc -o ${fastqcDir} --extract "${R1}" "${R2}" 2> /dev/null
 
  """
}

process runTrimmomatic {
   tag "Trimming adapter for ${sampleID}"
   publishDir "${params.output_dir}/Output/Trimmomatic"
   
   module params.modules.java    
   
   // Define input parameters
   input:
   set indivID, sampleID, libraryID, rgID, platform_unit, platform,
   platform_model, run_date, center, R1, R2 \
   from readInput_to_runTrimmomatic 
   file("${sampleID}_001.R1_fastqc/summary.txt") from runFastQC_to_runTrimmomatic_R1
   file("${sampleID}_001.R2_fastqc/summary.txt") from runFastQC_to_runTrimmomatic_R2

   
    // Define output parameters
    output:
    file("${trimmed_R1}") into trimmed_R1 
    file("${trimmed_R2}") into trimmed_R2

    script:
    
    trimmed_R1="${params.output_dir}/Output/Trimmomatic/trimmed_fastq/${sampleID}_R1_trimmed.fastq"
    trimmed_R2="${params.output_dir}/Output/Trimmomatic/trimmed_fastq/${sampleID}_R2_trimmed.fastq"
   
    """
    module list
    
    mkdir -p ${params.output_dir}/Output/Trimmomatic 
    
    // Check if the last line contains "fail" or "warn" in either R1 or R2 summary
    def lastLineR1 = file("${params.output_dir}/Samples/${sampleID}/fastqc/*_fastqc/summary.txt").text.readLines().last()
    
    if (lastLineR1 ==~ /fail|warn/) {
        echo "Adapter content detected in ${sampleID}, running Trimmomatic"
        java -jar ${params.PATH.adapter_path}/trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -threads 27 \
        ${R1} ${R2} \
        ${trimmed_R1} ${trimmed_R2} \
        ILLUMINACLIP:${params.PATH.adapter}:2:30:10:8:true \
        LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:20 MINLEN:50
    } else {
        echo "No adapter content detected in ${sampleID}, no need to run Trimmomatic"
        ln -s ${R1} ${trimmed_R1}
        ln -s ${R2} ${trimmed_R2}
    }
    """
}

workflow.onComplete {
  log.info ""
  log.info "========================================="
  log.info "Duration:       $workflow.duration"
  log.info "========================================="
}

// FUNCTIONS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Read input file and save it into a list of lists //////////////////////////////
def logParams(p, n) {
  File file = new File(n)
  file.write "Parameter:\tValue\n"

  for (s in p) {
    file << "${s.key}:\t${s.value}\n"
  }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `${sampleID}_001.R1_fastqc/summary.txt` expected by process `runFastQC (Checking adapter content for ${sampleID)`
```

The fastqc was successfully run and the *summary.txt* exists in the designated directory. However, it says it is missing. Any thought or better approach? Thank you so much!

Comment: It looks like the variable name might be incorrect to me. Can you add `echo ${sampleID}` 
and `ls *_fastqc/` to the script as we cannot see what the variables are actually named.

Also, do you need to make discrete channels for both the R1 and R2 output? Seems unnecessary. You could output both in a tuple, though you'd have to rename them to stop a file name collision- `set val($sampleID),  path(R1_summary.txt), path(R2_summary.txt)`

Comment: Thanks for replying! ${sampleID} are `FM_001__RNAseq__CGCTCATT-ATAGAGGC_ACAK6FANXX_L008`, `FM_002__RNAseq__ATTCAGAA-ATAGAGGC_ACAK6FANXX_L008`, `FM_003__RNAseq__GAGATTCC-ATAGAGGC_HL2TFDSXX_L004`, and etc. After the code above, it will produce a lot of files including summary.txt in `${params.output_dir}/Samples/${sampleID}/FastQC/${sampleID}_001.R1_fastqc` directory and R2 respectively. After outputting both in a tuple and adding two things you've suggested, I will let you know what I get.

Comment: Ah, I see one of the main problems. 

You should also not be giving nextflow processes absolute paths. Use the `publishDir` directive if you want publish files from the working directory.  The process is not finding the files because they don't exist in the process workDir. 

It's looking in something like `${launchDir)/work/ae/92asdksjfaa9a9s/${sampleID}_001.R2_fastqc/summary.txt`

Comment: A solution would be to remove `fastqcDir = "${params.output_dir}/Samples/${sampleID}/FastQC"`, and add an appropriate `publishDir` directive. Check nextflow documentation and best practices.